# Improper sorting when using filter and sort methods together in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I understand that I can sort an array in a more pragmatic way, by creating nested arrays as such :

```
                 [ [value,frequency], [value,frequency] ]
```

and sorting by the frequency.

However Im trying to use another approach because it makes sense in my head but for some reason I cant reason why its not working consistently.

Several tests are returning these puzzling results:

```js
    function arrOrd(arr){
    
    var arr_s=arr.sort(
    
      function(a,b) {
       var u=arr.filter(x=> x==a).length;
       var v=arr.filter(x=> x==b).length;       
       return u-v;    
    })
    
    return arr_s;    
    }

console.log(arrOrd([2,3,5,3,7,9,5,3,7]).toString());  //   ==>[9,2,7,7,5,5,3,3,3]
console.log(arrOrd([4,4,2,5,1,1,3,3,2,8]).toString()); //  ==>[8,5,4,4,2,1,1,3,3,2]
console.log(arrOrd([4,9,5,0,7,3,8,4,9,0]).toString()); //  ==>[8,3,7,5,4,9,0,4,9,0]
```

I think there is a new concept here that I am not grasping because I cant seem to find a solution myself. As always, thank you for your patience and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of an array during a sort is implementation-defined. Per [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort):

> 1. Perform an implementation-dependent sequence of calls to the [[Get]]
>      and [[Set]] internal methods of obj, to the DeletePropertyOrThrow and
>      HasOwnProperty abstract operation with obj as the first argument, and
>      to SortCompare (described below), such that:
>
>    - The property key argument for each call to [[Get]], [[Set]], HasOwnProperty, or DeletePropertyOrThrow is the string representation
>        of a nonnegative integer less than len.
>    - The arguments for calls to SortCompare are values returned by a previous call to the [[Get]] internal method, unless the properties
>        accessed by those previous calls did not exist according to
>        HasOwnProperty. If both perspective [sic] arguments to SortCompare
>        correspond to non-existent properties, use +0 instead of calling
>        SortCompare. If only the first perspective argument is non-existent
>        use +1. If only the second perspective argument is non-existent use
>        -1.
>    - If obj is not sparse then DeletePropertyOrThrow must not be called.
>    - If any [[Set]] call returns false a TypeError exception is thrown.
>    - If an abrupt completion is returned from any of these operations, it is immediately returned as the value of this function.

In other words, a perfectly valid implementation of sort for a JavaScript engine would be to make a copy of the array, replace all the elements in the original with `"hi"`, perform the sort on the copy, and replace all the elements back.

If you’re curious about the exact state of the array during each comparison – log it!

```js
const arr = [5, 2, 3, 1, 4];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
    console.log(arr.join(' '));
    return a - b;
});
```

In Firefox 60, this always logs the original state of the array; in Chrome 64, it logs several states, some with duplicate elements that the original array didn’t contain.